# Spark DataFrame/DataSet pagination or iterate chunk of N row at a time

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to implement pagination for my dataset ( in spark scala).

If 100 records in spark dataset then i need to split into 20 batch with 5 element in each batch.

Please how to split spark dataset/dataframe to N number of row?

--NS

Comment: Do you want to perform further relational operations on these split Datasets?

Comment: What is your use case ? What do you want to do on the batched data ? By batching, are you trying to distribute the data to avoid skew ?

Comment: Each batched will be send to another function to get data from oracle . Oracle IN class have limitation ( only 1000 value max), so i passed data set with max 100 row now. Thanks Terry and constantine

Comment: how can we achieve this in pyspark?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you want to perform further relational operations on these split Datasets? If not and if you only have in the order of 100 rows then I would do something like

```
ds.collect.grouped(5)
```

Comment: Thanks Terry for your quick response . I tried  grouped method and its working for my requirement. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if there is a better approach but you could try: transform your dataframe into rdd, use `zipWithIndex`, filter and then convert to dataframe again.

For example, suppose your dataframe is given by

```
scala> val df=sc.parallelize(1 to 100).toDF("value")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: int]

scala> df.show()
+-----+
|value|
+-----+
|    1|
|    2|
|    3|
|    4|
|    5|
|    6|
|    7|
|    8|
|    9|
|   10|
|   11|
|   12|
|   13|
|   14|
|   15|
|   16|
|   17|
|   18|
|   19|
|   20|
+-----+
only showing top 20 rows
```

Convert to rdd and zip with index as follows: `val dfRDD=df.rdd.zipWithIndex`

```
scala> val dfRDD=df.rdd.zipWithIndex
dfRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(org.apache.spark.sql.Row, Long)] = ZippedWithIndexRDD[81] at zipWithIndex at <console>:69
```

For your first dataframe containing rows 1 to 5, filter as follows:

```
val firstDF=dfRDD.filter{case(datum,index)=>(0 to 4).contains(index)}.map(_._1)
scala> val firstDF=dfRDD.filter{case(datum,index)=>(0 to 4).contains(index)}.map(_._1)
firstDF: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = MapPartitionsRDD[85] at map at <console>:71
```

Finally, transform to dataframe as follows: `sqlContext.createDataFrame(firstDF,df.schema)`

```
scala> sqlContext.createDataFrame(firstDF,df.schema).show()
+-----+
|value|
+-----+
|    1|
|    2|
|    3|
|    4|
|    5|
+-----+
```

You have to repeat these steps for the remaining rows `(5 to 9)`, `(10 to 14)`, etc.

EDIT: To make things a bit faster, I defined a method

```
def splitDF(range:scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame={
    val mySplitRDD=dfRDD.filter{case(datum,index)=>range.contains(index)}.map(_._1)
    val mySplitDF=sqlContext.createDataFrame(mySplitRDD,df.schema)
    mySplitDF
}
```

Then use a map to get all the splits, for example

```
val dataframes=List((0 to 4), (5 to 9),(10 to 14)).map(i=>splitDF(i))

scala> val dataframes=List((0 to 4), (5 to 9),(10 to 14)).map(i=>splitDF(i))
dataframes: List[org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame] = List([value: int], [value: int], [value: int])
```

Dataframe 2:

```
scala> dataframes(1).show()
+-----+
|value|
+-----+
|    6|
|    7|
|    8|
|    9|
|   10|
+-----+
```

Dataframe 1:

```
scala> dataframes(0).show()
+-----+
|value|
+-----+
|    1|
|    2|
|    3|
|    4|
|    5|
+-----+
```

Dataframe 3:

```
scala> dataframes(2).show()
+-----+
|value|
+-----+
|   11|
|   12|
|   13|
|   14|
|   15|
+-----+
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help and effort  you put for answering this question.